# Error code : 11581 - Profile description is invalid in paypal

Tags: paypal, profile

7 days ago, I have created a sandbox merchant account and make all the payment into that account.
I have created Recurring payment. It was successfully create the Recurring profile.

Some days later when I execute the same code its throws an error "Profile description is invalid". The error code of the error is 11581.

Please help me. I want to solve the problem as soon as possible

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Profile description length is 127 single-byte alphanumeric characters. This might be the problem

DESC

(Required) Description of the recurring payment.

Note You must ensure that this field **matches the corresponding billing agreement description** included in the SetExpressCheckout request.

Character length and limitations: 127 single-byte alphanumeric characters

[Here is the Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)

**Edit : From comment below ->  Also check for line breaks and double spaces**
Thanks @chim

Comment: Also check for line breaks and double spaces

Comment: @chim: You saved my day... :) I was getting this error in Magento CE 1.9... Your comment helped me to track error.. There was extra space in 'DESC' field for recurring payment request... Thanks !!!!

Comment: The **L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0** in **SetExpressCheckout** it has to be the same of **DESC** in **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile**

Answer (score 2):

The **L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0** in **SetExpressCheckout** it has to be the same of **DESC** in **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile**